# requeststreams in lightopenid queries URL twice, getting success (is_valid:true) the first time but returning the second result, which is failure

Tags: php, openid, lightopenid

I have implemented logon code on a local test machine (Windows & IIS), and on a remote server.  In IIS, it "works", taking the request_curl route.  On the server, it takes the request_streams route, and fails.

By inserting a lot of trace messages in the code, I find that it in fact succeeds, then fails.  Here's how:

In request_streams, the statement

```
       $data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

returns "is_valid:true...".  Unfortunately, the code goes on to deal with response headers and then executes a statement identical to the one above, which this time returns "is_valid:false...".

Since I'm unsure of what request_streams is really trying to do at this point, I'm loathe to simply delete the problem statement and return $data.

Can anyone explain what the code should be doing here?  Does the code need fixing, or might I have done something to muck it up somehow?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug with the current stable version. Use the [version from gitorious](https://gitorious.org/lightopenid/lightopenid/blobs/raw/master/openid.php), which has it fixed.